# How to backreference in Ruby regular expression (regex) with gsub when I use grouping?

Tags: ruby, regex, reference, gsub, backreference

I would like to patch some text data extracted from web pages.
sample:

```
t="First sentence. Second sentence.Third sentence."
```

There is no space after the point at the end of the second sentence. This sign me that the 3rd sentence was in a separate line (after a br tag) in the original document.

I want to use this regexp to insert "\n" character into the proper places and patch my text.
My regex:

```
t2=t.gsub(/([.\!?])([A-Z1-9])/,$1+"\n"+$2)
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work: "NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass"
How can I properly backreference to the matched groups?
It was so easy in Microsoft Word, I just had to use \1 and \2 symbols.

Comment: The numbered globals (`$1`, `$2`, ...) aren't set when the second argument is evaluated, they're set by `gsub` before it yields to the block. Hence sawa's advice on when to use `'\1'` and when to use `$1`.

Answer (score 34):

You can backreference in the substitution string with `\1` (to match capture group 1).

```
t = "First sentence. Second sentence.Third sentence!Fourth sentence?Fifth sentence."
t.gsub(/([.!?])([A-Z1-9])/, "\\1\n\\2") # => "First sentence. Second sentence.\nThird sentence!\nFourth sentence?\nFifth sentence."
```

Answer (score 26):

- If you are using `gsub(regex, replacement)`, then use `'\1'`, `'\2'`, ... to refer to the match. Make sure not to put double quotes around the `replacement`, or else escape the backslash as in Joshua's answer. The conversion from `'\1'` to the match will be done within `gsub`, not by literal interpretation.
- If you are using `gsub(regex){replacement}`, then use `$1`, `$1`, ...

But for your case, it is easier not to use matches:

```
t2 = t.gsub(/(?<=[.\!?])(?=[A-Z1-9])/, "\n")
```

Comment: He'll have to use double quotes to get the newline or `'\1' + "\n" + '\2'`.

Comment: @muistooshort The OP is originally using `+`, so what you gave was what I had in mind.

Answer (score 8):

If you got here because of Rubocop complaining "Avoid the use of Perl-style backrefs." about $1, $2, etc... you can can do this instead:

```
some_id = $1
# or
some_id = Regexp.last_match[1] if Regexp.last_match

some_id = $5
# or
some_id = Regexp.last_match[5] if Regexp.last_match
```

It'll also want you to do

```
%r{//}.match(some_string)
```

instead of

```
some_string[//]
```

Lame (Rubocop)