# Ruby regex to find words starting with @

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I'm trying to write a very simple regex to find all words in a string that start with the symbol `@`. Then change the word to a link. Like you would see in a Twitter where you can mention other usernames.

So far I have written this

```
def username_link(s)
  s.gsub(/\@\w+/, "<a href='/username'>username</a>").html_safe
end
```

I know it's very basic and not much, but I'd rather write it on my own right now, to fully understand it, before searching GitHub to find a more complex one.

What I'm trying to find out is how can I reference that matched word and include it in the place of `username`. Once I can do that i can easily strip the first character, `@`, out of it.

Thanks.

Comment: Make use of backreferences?

Comment: Correct. Thanks for the comment @devnull. Like what I did with that reference?? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture using parentheses and backreference with `\1` (and `\2`, and so on):

```
def username_link(s)
    s.gsub(/@(\w+)/, "<a href='/\\1'>\\1</a>").html_safe
end
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065707/how-to-backreference-in-ruby-regular-expression-regex-with-gsub-when-i-use-gro)

Comment: @7stud, do you have a better solution for this problem?

Comment: @Justin, Not yet, but here is my test string `"@tim @tim @tim, @@tim, t@mmy?"`

Comment: This would not work for string like "Hi someone@company" as it would still replace it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `gsub` with back references:

```
str = "I know it's very basic and not much, but @tim I'd rather write it on my own."

def username_to_link(str)
  str.gsub(/\@(\w+)/, '<a href="\1">@\1</a>')
end

puts username_to_link(str)
#=> I know it's very basic and not much, but <a href="tim">@tim</a> I'd rather write it on my own.
```

Comment: But I'm still trying to display the entire string, just replacing the matched word, with the link.

Comment: @Justin good clarification. rjz has the best answer.. Just his gsub is  a little fugly. I updated my answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Following Regex should handle corner cases which other answers ignore

```
def auto_username_link(s)
  s.gsub(/(^|\s)\@(\w+)($|\s)/, "\\1<a href='/\\2'>\\2</a>\\3").html_safe
end
```

It should ignore strings like "someone@company" or "@username-1" while converting everything like "Hello @username rest of message"

Comment: What about:  `str = "@tim @tim @tim, @@tim,@tim t@mmy?"`. Arguably there should be at least 4 substitutions in that string. Your regex produces only one substitution and it incorrectly removes a space.  And if there should be a substitution at ",@tim", then why not at "@@tim"?  Both the characters "," and "@" are non-word characters, so why treat them differently?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
def convert_names_to_links(str)
  str = " " + str

  result = str.gsub(
    /
      (?<=\W)   #Look for a non-word character(space/punctuation/etc.) preceeding
      @         #an "@" character, followed by
      (\w+)     #a word character, one or more times
    /xm,        #Standard normalizing flags
    '<a href="/\1">@\1</a>'
  )

  result[1..-1]
end

my_str = "@tim @tim @tim, @@tim,@tim t@mmy?"
puts convert_names_to_links(my_str)
```

--output:--

[@tim](/tim) [@tim](/tim) [@tim](/tim), @[@tim](/tim),[@tim](/tim) t@mmy?

Comment: Note the code will also produce two substitutions here: `"Hi @tim!@tim, you are great!"` and one substitution here `"Hello !@tim."`